# Programa para trocar a diagaonal primária e a diagonal secundária de matriz (sem numpy)

Tags: python, python-3.x, matriz

Seja a matriz abaixo forma por uma lista de listas:

```
matriz = [[4, 24, 11, 30, 12],
         [1, 2, 1, 13, 12],
         [4, 5, 24, 9, 23],
         [5, 26, 17, 29, 6],
         [20, 12, 21, 30, 9]]
```

O que eu fiz:

```
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(m):
        if i == j: #diagonal principal
            for x in range(n):
                for y in range(m):
                    if x + y == m - 1:
                        if x==y:# i!=j para nao mover o elemento comum as 2 diag
                            break
                        else:
                            matriz[i][j], matriz[x][y] =  matriz[x][y], matriz[i][j]
print(matriz)
```

Saída:

```
[[20, 24, 11, 30, 9],
 [1, 26, 1, 29, 12],
 [4, 5, 13, 9, 23],
 [5, 24, 17, 12, 6],
 [2, 12, 21, 30, 4]]
```

Fiquei com a dúvida:
Inicialmente o número 24 era um elemento comum as duas diagonais (Primária e secundária): ele não deveria permanecer na mesma posição?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se me lembro bem das aulas de matemática, vamos ter diagonal principal e diagonal secundária só em matrizes quadradas, por isso, é possível utilizar apenas uma variável, por exemplo *i*, ao invés de 4 (*i, j, x, y*) e baseado nessa variável *i* vamos caminhando de fora pra dentro.

Segue duas soluções, onde a segunda (troca_cima_baixo()) é que acredito apresentar maior rigor matemático considerando as definições de diagonal principal e diagonal secundária:

Código:

```
matriz = [
    [ 4, 24, 11, 30, 12],
    [ 1,  2,  1, 13, 12],
    [ 4,  5, 24,  9, 23],
    [ 5, 26, 17, 29,  6],
    [20, 12, 21, 30,  9]
    ]

#Trocando as diagonais pelas laterais
def troca_esq_dir(matriz):
    for i in range(len(matriz)):
        matriz[i][i], matriz[-i - 1][i] = matriz[-i - 1][i], matriz[i][i]

#trocando as diagonais pelo topo e fundo
def troca_cima_baixo(matriz):
    for i in range(len(matriz)):
        matriz[i][i], matriz[i][-i -1] = matriz[i][-i -1], matriz[i][i]
```

Pelas Laterais:

```
troca_esq_dir(matriz)
print(matriz)
```

Saída:

```
[
[20, 24, 11, 30,  9],
[ 1, 26,  1, 29, 12],
[ 4,  5, 24,  9, 23],
[ 5,  2, 17, 13,  6],
[ 4, 12, 21, 30, 12]
]
```

Pelo topo e fundo:

```
troca_cima_baixo(matriz)
print(matriz)
```

Saída:

```
[
[12, 24, 11, 30,  4],
[ 1, 13,  1,  2, 12],
[ 4,  5, 24,  9, 23],
[ 5, 29, 17, 26,  6],
[ 9, 12, 21, 30, 20]
]
```

Comment: Não entendi o [-i -1]

Comment: @EdS no python podemos utilizar index negativo nos vetores pra selecionar elementos a partir do fim do vetor.
O elemento vetor[-1] será o último elemento do vetor, vetor[-2] o penúltimo e assim por diante...
se utilizássemos -i iriamos começar em -0, que não existe, e caminharíamos até o segundo elemento do vetor mas sem iterar com o primeiro elemento quando i for len(vetor)-1, por isso utilizamos o -i-1, caminhando de -1 até -len(vetor)